# How to update KendoGrid from combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a web app in ASP.NET MVC using Kendo UI. I'm visualizing data in a Kendo Grid as follows:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
  .Name("grid")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource // Configure the grid data source
      .Ajax() // Specify that ajax binding is used
      .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAction", "MyController", new { /*route values*/ }))
    )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(n => n.Month).Title("Month").ClientTemplate("<input type='hidden' value='#=Month#' id='hfMonth'/>").Hidden();
      columns.AutoGenerate(true);          

  })
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable()
```

Now I need to fire an update of the grid based on the change event of a `<select>`. How can I do this? I'm trying several possibilities from yesterday, with no success as all.

Comment: When your changes are applied. Call this in a JS function `$('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code for the combobox I would do the following:

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
      .Name("combo")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
          new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "Foo", Value = "1"   
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "Bar", Value = "2"   
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "Baz", Value = "3"   
          }
      })
  .Events(events =>
  {
    events.Change("onChange");
  })
)
```

**JavaScript**

```
function onChange(e) {

  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  // if the selected value is not needed
  grid.dataSource.read();

  // if the selected value is needed use below instead
  // changing the route parameter to match yours
  var selectedValue = this.Value();
  grid.dataSource.read({ id : selectedValue });
}
```

**Update**

As per @PierpaoloIlConteParis comments:

> I didn't specify directly the parameters in the read.Action method, but instead I used the handler function like in this post [telerik.com/forums/…](http://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-additional-parameters-to-read-ajax-datasource-method---mvc#6-wwFQboTECQByGUQYKKhw) Now when changing the combobox value the action fires with right parameters

Comment: Thank you very much. The action of the data source takes some parameters. How can I tell "The action needs a parameter with this name"?
Now I have something like this:
.Read(read => read.Action("YearAggregation", "MyController", new { [at]year = 2015, [at]productId = 1 }))
2015 and 1 are the defaults. I must write [at] because Stackoverflow doesn't like the "at" symbol.

Comment: @PierpaoloIlConteParis No probs. It is this part here: `grid.dataSource.read({ id : selectedValue });` in this example the route value is `id`, just change it to your parameter name instead.

Comment: Ok, a workaround worked like a charm. I didn't specify directly the parameters in the read.Action method, but instead I used the handler function like in this post http://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-additional-parameters-to-read-ajax-datasource-method---mvc#6-wwFQboTECQByGUQYKKhw
Now when changing the combobox value the action fires with right parameters. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PierpaoloIlConteParis Nice one, I will update my answer with your comments. :)